# How can I ignore ValueError when I try to remove an element from a list?

Tags: python, list, error-handling, element

How can I ignore the "not in list" error message if I call `a.remove(x)` when `x` is not present in list `a`?

This is my situation:

```
>>> a = range(10)
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> a.remove(10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
>>> a.remove(9)
```

Comment: Why wouldn't Python list also have Python [set's discard operation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.discard)? `discard` removes element from the set if it is present.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

A good and thread-safe way to do this is to just try it and ignore the exception:

```
try:
    a.remove(10)
except ValueError:
    pass  # do nothing!
```

Answer (score 67):

I'd personally consider using a `set` instead of a `list` as long as the order of your elements isn't necessarily important.  Then you can use the discard method:

```
>>> S = set(range(10))
>>> S
set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> S.remove(10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 10
>>> S.discard(10)
>>> S
set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Comment: Using a `set` when not appropriate can have unintended consequences.  From the documentation, [`Remove the first item from the list whose value is x. It is an error if there is no such item.`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)  OP may want to only remove the first item in other use cases, indicating valid duplicates within the list.

Answer (score 37):

As an alternative to ignoring the `ValueError`

```
try:
    a.remove(10)
except ValueError:
    pass  # do nothing!
```

I think the following is a little more straightforward and readable:

```
if 10 in a:
    a.remove(10)
```

Comment: It's a good thought, but as @Niklas B. points out, his is "thread-safe", because no matter what, 10 not being there can only ever cause a *caught* exception. Whereas in this answer, `10` could be removed from `a` between the `if` condition being checked and `.remove()` being called, resulting in an *uncaught* `ValueError`. (If you can make a guarantee about `a` not being modified by anything else, then this is fine, but with the accepted answer you don't even have to think about that possibility.)

Comment: For lambda expressions, it can sometimes be helpful to have a one-liner for the same purpose, and in that case `a in 10 and a.remove(10)` does the job. It's also not thread-safe though.

Comment: Kinda torn on this one ... at what point do you abandon the [zen of python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) for thread safety?  Certainly if you are writing a library module that is likely to be used in a multithreaded app you will need to make things more complex and/or document its thread safety (or lack thereof), but should one try to do that in general?

Comment: @reteptilian I think it is not actually the "thread safety" rather than it is "[Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission.](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html?highlight=eafp#term-eafp)"

Comment: If you care about thread safety you should be using explicit locking.

Comment: Do we also not double the number of comparisons in the second approach with `if`: first we are looking for `10` in the list during `in` operation, and then again in `remove` operation?  While `try` does this in one go, no?  How do the two methods compare in performance when we are removing an element from a very long list?

Answer (score 8):

How about list comprehension?

```
a = [x for x in a if x != 10]
```

Comment: Please explain why think this an improvement over the accepted answer.

Comment: @Melvyn, I primarily offered it as an alternative, not necessarily an "improvement".  I like that it's one line and readable.

Comment: This creates a new list, which is less efficient than modifying an existing one, _especially_ if the item is not found and no copying of elements needs to be done.

Comment: Furthermore, it may break references to the existing list, e.g. `a = ['foo']; b = a; a = [x for x in a if x != 'bar']; a.append('baz'); print(b)` will print `['foo']` whereas using `remove` will print `['foo', 'baz']`. As such I don't consider this a viable generalized alternative to `try/remove/except` or `if/in/remove`.

Answer (score 7):

When I only care to ensure the entry is not in a list, dict, or set I use contextlib like so:

```
import contextlib

some_list = []
with contextlib.suppress(ValueError):
    some_list.remove(10)

some_set = set()
some_dict = dict()
with contextlib.suppress(KeyError):
    some_set.remove('some_value')
    del some_dict['some_key']
```

Comment: This is in my opinion the correct answer for Python3 - You can use it as elegant one liner like : `with suppress(ValueError): mylist.remove("whatever")`

Comment: Best and most generic answer also for me

Answer (score 4):

i think the most simple way(may not best way) is write down if statement to check this value is in the list or not, then remove it from list.

```
if 10 in a:
    a.remove(10)
```

Answer (score 3):

A better way to do this would be

```
source_list = list(filter(lambda x: x != element_to_remove,source_list))
```

Because in a more complex program, the exception of `ValueError` could also be raised for something else and a few answers here just pass it, thus discarding it while creating more possible problems down the line.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for a 1 liner as me:

```py
10 not in a or a.remove(10)
```

Answer (score -5):

you have typed wrong input.
syntax: list.remove(x)

and x is the element of your list.
in remove parenthesis ENTER what already have in your list.
ex: a.remove(2)

i have entered 2 because it has in list.
I hape this data help you.

Comment: The question is specifically about how to ignore the error when attempting to remove something from a list that *isn't* in that list.