# How can I make it so that while using the data.remove function, it will keep removing even if the number isn't there in python?

Tags: python, arrays

```
def mainprogram(sub):

    if sub < 100:
        print("You didn't type an integer over 100.")
        quit()

    #---------------multiples of 2------------
    counter = 3
    numberset = list(range(1,sub + 1))
    while counter < len(numberset):
        numberset.pop(counter)
        counter = counter + 1
        
    #-------------every other multiples of 3, since all multiples of 2 are gone-----------------

    counter = 9
    while counter in numberset:
        numberset.remove(counter)
        counter = counter + 6
        
    #---------multiples of 7-----------
    
    counter = 14
    while counter in numberset:
       numberset.remove(counter)
       counter = counter + 7
```

My problem is that the program breaks whenever I try to remove a number that isn't there. Since 21 is divisible by 3, it is already gone. When the program hits 21, it breaks the loop and stops removing numbers divisible by 7. I want to make it so that it continues to remove even if it hits a number that isn't there. I have tried multiple things such as using (array.pop), continue function, specifying the array with numberset[counter2] but nothing I have tried works. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I ignore ValueError when I try to remove an element from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915339/how-can-i-ignore-valueerror-when-i-try-to-remove-an-element-from-a-list)

Comment: Your naming is confusing. `numberset` is actually a list, when it really should have been a `set`

Comment: `[i for i in range(1, sub + 1, 2) if i % 3 != 0 and i % 7 != 0]`